# Make a png file where all the images are stuck, thanks to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a png file where all the images are pasted without ever having white stripes between each image and this whatever the number of columns or rows chosen (nb_cols and nb_rows in the small example below).

Indeed, currently, according to the nb_rows and nb_cols defined, there are white bands vertically and/or horizontally whereas I would like that all the images are stuck (no white bands) in all the cases.

What do I need to improve in the code below and what did I not understand?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nb_rows = 3
nb_col = 7

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.4803, 9.0551))
a = np.random.random((100, 130))

for ind in range(0, nb_rows*nb_col):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(nb_rows, nb_col, ind+1)
    ax.imshow(a,
              interpolation="nearest",
              origin="lower",
              extent=[0, 100, 0, 130])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.axis("off")

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1,
                        wspace=0, hspace=0)

fig.savefig('test.png', format="png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

**EDIT1:**
I change the little script above to easily see if the proportions are kept in the final image (I want the subimages to keep the size of the matrix (width == 1 and height =1.5).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nb_rows = 3
nb_col = 7

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.4803, 9.0551))
#a = np.random.random((100, 13))


for ind in range(0, nb_rows*nb_col):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(nb_rows, nb_col, ind+1)
    if ind % 2 == 0:
        a = np.zeros((150,100))
    else:
        a = np.ones((150, 100))
   # a = np.zeros((150,100))
    ax.imshow(a,
              vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Greys_r",
              interpolation="nearest",
              origin="lower",
              extent=[0, 100, 0, 150],
              aspect='auto')
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.axis("off")

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1,
                        wspace=0, hspace=0)

fig.savefig('test.png', format="png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

With aspect='auto' in imshow() we loose the initial proportions (1/1.5).

**EDIT2:**
The ImageGrid seems to do the job. Below is a small adaptation of the previous code as an example (in addition the code may look even simpler now).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

nb_rows = 2
nb_col = 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.4803, 9.0551))


grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(nb_rows, nb_col),
                 axes_pad=0,
                 )
ind=0

for ax in grid:
    if ind % 2 == 0:
        a = np.zeros((150,100))
    else:
        a = np.ones((150, 100))

    ind +=1

    ax.imshow(a,
              vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Greys_r",
              interpolation="nearest",
              origin="lower",
              extent=[0, 100, 0, 150],
              aspect='auto')
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.axis("off")

fig.savefig('test3.png', format="png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

Comment: add `aspect='auto'` to `imshow`

Comment: You can also use axes_grid for this: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_axes_grid.html

Comment: @Stef, This is a good idea, except with aspect='auto' in imshow() we loose the initial proportions ... I edited the question for this.

Comment: another option could be to first combine the images (i.e. their numpy arrays) into one big image and then plot this one

Comment: @JodyKlymak, yes ImageGrid() is exactly what I need ! Thanks !